# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on UIAlertview code=1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uialertview, exc-bad-access

I am getting the EXC_BAD_ACCESS on [alert show] line.

Why I am getting this?

```
 alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Application Alert" message:@"all date popup" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Update",nil];

 [alert show]; //EXC_BAD_ACCESS on this line
```

Comment: check out my answer given here  [http://stackoverflow.com/a/13084383/1538079]

Comment: Are you calling it from the main thread?

Comment: what is the prototype for 'alert'..

Comment: I am calling it in main thread. Prototype of alert is UIAlertView.

Comment: @Foram Mukund Shah It's a little weird when you say `main thread gets finish`, what did you mean ?

Comment: by main thread I don't mean the background thread. By that I meant the thread from which alertview is invoking

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just make delegate nil ,don't apply self to delegate .code it like below

```
alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Application Alert" message:@"all date popup" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Update",nil];

[alert show];
```

if you are using self in delegate then you will have to use alert delegate method

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

then it will not give EXC_Bad_Excess.let me know if it works..!!!!happy coding....

Answer (score 16):

This crash must be on iOS 6. Solution for this crash is as follow :

`[alert performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];`

Comment: This is the correct solution if it errs because you are calling `[alert show]` from the background.